# Do all four kids of Logan Roy have the same mother?

Tags: succession

At the end of Succession S01 we meet Shiv's mother at the wedding. Is she a mother to all of the four siblings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They've yet to name Logan's first wife, who is the mother of Connor. We met his second wife and his third wife, who is technically a step mother to them all.

- [Caroline Collingwood](https://succession.fandom.com/wiki/Caroline_Collingwood): Kendall Roy, Roman Roy and Shiv Roy
- Unnamed Mother: [Connor Roy](https://succession.fandom.com/wiki/Connor_Roy)

Comment: This is what I vaguely remember as well, but do you remember when in the series this was established?  If so, it would be good to edit your answer to include that information. (Also, welcome to [Movies.SE]!)

Comment: Ah, here we go.  In S01E02, Kendall (IIRC?) is reviewing Logan's pre-taped obituary, and says to his assistant "Hey Jess?  There's nothing in here about our mom, or Connor's.  They need to be included."